# Swap adjacent element in a linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

While seeing a programming interview site, I came across code which swap adjacent elements in a linked list, but I found it to be a bit wrong. Below is the code.

```
void swap (struct list **list1)
{
    struct list *cur, *tmp, *next;
    cur = *list1;
    if (cur && cur->next)
        *list1 = cur->next;

    //To make sure that we have at least two more elements to be swapped.
    while (cur && cur->next)
    {
        next = cur->next;
        tmp = next->next;
        next->next = cur;
        //We have to make 1->next as 4 in above example (figure).

        if (tmp)
            cur->next = tmp->next;
        cur = tmp;
    }
    return;
}
```

Now for me, the condition `if (temp)` is not right here. Is that assessment correct?

Suppose we do have a linked list like:

```
  1->2->3->4->NULL
```

Now our objective is to make a linked list like:

```
2->1->4->3->NULL
```

My worry is if the `if (temp)` is there in our code, we can't assign null at end of the linked list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right. This doesn't work. It creates a loop at the end of the list, and if you run `swap` twice on the same list, the second run will get into an endless loop.

To fix this awkward code, replace the `if (tmp)` with the following code:

```
if(tmp)
    if (tmp->next)
        cur->next = tmp->next;
    else
        cur->next = tmp;    // take care of an add number of nodes
else
    cur->next = NULL;   // take care of an even number of nodes
```

It will take care of the last nodes:

1. If there's an even number of nodes, it makes sure the last points to NULL instead of the node before it.
2. If there's an odd number of nodes, checking `cur->next` will prevent the following iteration, so the last node must be pointed by the one before it before the loop is exited.

Comment: Thanks for your response @Eran .i think if we simply remove this particular line if(tmp), code should work fine without any other modification.

Comment: @Amit, removing the `if (tmp)` won't make it work - you'd still have a loop at the end of the list, and if the list has an odd number of nodes, you'd also loose the last one. I really hope this code was intentionally made confusing for the sake of the interview. In real world, you'd better just separate the list implementation from its content, and use `std::list<data*>` or so. Would make it so much easier to swap `data*`s...

Comment: @Amit, just wondering - you first accepted this answer, and then un-accepted it (or however that's called...). Any special reason why this doesn't answer your question anymore?

Answer (score 2):

It tests it to make sure it's not `NULL` (the last element). Not testing it will make your program follow the NULL pointer for the last element of the list.

```
tmp = next->next; /* If `next` is the last, `next->next` is NULL. */
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are right that there's a bug in the function - `cur->next` isn't updated correctly in all cases.

I personally find the local variable names `tmp` and `next` not particularly helpful and actively confusing in the case of `next`. Those names make it hard for me to keep track in my head of what's going on as I read through the function.

I find that the names `node1`, `node2`, and `node3` work better to for me to keep a mental picture of which node is being manipulated.  I wouldn't be surprised if other people disagree, though.

Here's a reworked version of the function that I find more readable, and more importantly that I believe is correct.

```
void swap (struct list **head)
{
    struct list *node1 = *head;
    struct list *node2 = node1 ? node1->next : NULL;

    // handle degenerate cases
    if (!node2) {
        // no elements or only one element on the list
        //  nothing to do...
        return;
    }    

    // fix-up list head to what will be the new first node on list
    *head = node2;        

    // while there are at least 2 more elements to be swapped
    while (node1 && node2) {
        struct list* node3 = node2->next;

        // get a pointer to the node that will be the remainder of the
        //  list after the remainder of the list is processed.  
        //
        // This will be NULL, node3, or 'node4' depending on whether 
        //  there are 0 , 1 or 2+ nodes following node1 and node2
        struct list* remainder = (node3 && node3->next) ? node3->next : node3;

        node1->next = remainder;
        node2->next = node1;

        // prepare pointers to the next two nodes to be swapped
        node1 = node3;
        node2 = node3 ? node3->next : NULL;
    }

    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Java Implementation**

Given: `1->2->3->4->5->6`

Logic
 1. First - 1, Second - 2, Third 3
 2. Second.next = first
 3. First.next = Third.next depending on even or odd numbers update accordingly

```
public ListNode evenOddMerge(ListNode head) {

        if (head == null || head.next == null) {
            return head;
        }

        ListNode first = head;
        ListNode second = first.next;
        ListNode third = null;

        head = second;

        while (true) {

            third = second.next;

            second.next = first;

            if (third == null || third.next == null) {
                first.next = third;
                break;
            }

            first.next = third.next;

            first = third;
            second = first.next;
        }

        return head;
    }
```

Credits: [Geeks for Geeks](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pairwise-swap-elements-of-a-given-linked-list-by-changing-links/)